# Need to get element from url

Tags: element, price

I have a url that looks like this

```
<span class="price" itemprop="lowPrice">14,70 €</span>
```

and i want to get the 14,70 € from this .

I have this

```
$url = "http://www.skroutz.gr/s/292655/Kingston-1GB-SODIMM-DDR3-Non-ECC-CL9-1333MHz.html";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$DOM = new DOMDocument();
@$DOM->loadHTML( $output);





//get all 
$items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('li');
//display all
   for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
       echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br/>";
```

but i get everything tagged with li . Is there a way just to get the 14,70 € ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Why are you parsing `li`'s when your text is in a span?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to extract the price from `$span` where `$span` =

```
<span class="price" itemprop="lowPrice">14,70 €</span>
```

A couple of `preg_replace()` calls will get it:

```
# remove span tag from beginning of string
$span = preg_replace('/^<span[^>]*>/', '', $span) ;
#remove span tag from end of string
$span = preg_replace('/<\/span.*$/', '', $span) ;
```

Comment: i am sorry i probably wasnt very clear, this gets me all span in the page. 0
8,25 €
1
4.9                                                                                         i want to get only this specific one